# How to add an existing key into another

Tags: gnupg

I have two pairs of keys for two mail accounts. Lets say mail1@one.net and mail2@two.net. how can add the second one into the first key? I know that I can use addkey but this does not remove the mail2 's keys. I remember I had found an article to do this once but I can find it anymore.

Comment: Can I just clarify that you want to *add* the uid `mail2@two.net` to `key_1`? I'm not sure what you mean by *"but this does not remove the mail2 's keys"* - do you mean that you would also like to delete `key_2` (with its single associated uid `mail2@two.net`) ?

Comment: yes i think you are saying the same thing. sorry for my english